# swift: print \r character in debug

Tags: ios, swift

I use this text `text\r2`. And I want to print this in debug and get result:

```
text\r2
```

but I get this:

```
text
2
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what OS are you using? On Unix systems (including Mac), you should get `2ext` -- `\r` moves to the beginning of the line, without moving down a line like the return key does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` in a String literal is a special character and represents a carriage return

See [Special Characters in String Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

```
String literals can include the following special characters:

 * The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \\ (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double quotation mark) and \' (single quotation mark)
 * An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point (Unicode is discussed in Unicode below)
```

If you want to use in a String Literal a backslash you have to escape it using `\\`.

So you'll have to write

```
print("text\\r2")
```

to get  `text\r2`

Comment: I understand this is not welcomed by the community. But could you please help with this problem. I just don't know what to do. Thanks! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851479/audio-files-wont-play-with-airpods-pro-on-ios-15

Answer (score 2):

Try to escape the backslash with another backslash: `text\\r2`.

The `\r` will otherwise be interpreted as a line break.